# How many numbers should I take to make sure

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I'm gonna take some numbers from $\{1,2,3,...,100\}$. How many numbers should I take to make sure that the sum of two number is equal or greater than $30$

The answer is $16$, but I can't figure out why
I answered $15$, because it's in the choice and I tried adding 
$$
1+2+3+4+5+...+15
$$
But the sum is greater than $30$, but the answer is $16$. Can someone please tell me why? Thank you.

I made an edit

Comment: I think I've missed something, because the answer looks like it should be 8?

Comment: Maybe they mean that the sum of any two numbers from your sample is equal to or greater than $30$ because then the answer is indeed $16$.

Comment: ^Great guess.{}{}{}

Comment: Please fix the question text if it is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I think I've figured it out.

You wish to pick enough numbers that it is guaranteed that *some pair of them* adds up to at least $30$.

In order for that to happen you need to consider the possibility that you're getting just the small numbers.  If you start with the first $15$ numbers, well, $14+15=29$, so you need to get at least one more number (which then must be at least $16$) to get there.  Then, $15+16 = 31$, and even $14+16=30$.

Answer (score 2):

If you are taking them without replacement, $8$ is correct.  As you point out $$1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8=36 \gt 30$$  The sum of the first $n$ numbers is $\frac 12n(n+1)$, the $n^{th}$ [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).
If you are taking them with replacement you need $30$ because you could get all $1$'s

Answer (score 1):

We have (since we are looking at the "worst case scenario")

$$
1+2+3+\ldots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$

You want this to be greater than $30$, so

$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\ge 30
$$
so
$$
n^2+n-60\ge0
$$
so
$$
\Big(n+\frac{1}{2} \Big)^2-\frac{1}{4}-60\ge0
$$
that is
$$
\Big(n+\frac{1}{2} \Big)^2-\frac{241}{4}\ge0
$$
therefore
$$
\Big(n+\frac{1}{2} \Big)^2\ge\frac{241}{4}
$$
which means
$$
n\ge\frac{-1+\sqrt{241}}{2}\approx\frac{-1+15,524174696}{2}  \approx\frac{-1+16}{2}=7,5\approx 8.
$$

This is obviously without replacement. For the case with replacement we have $30$ *ones*.

I have no idea why the answer was $16$. Are you sure you remember the question withall its details correctly?

Comment: The OP can be wrong in that

Comment: In your first line the $n-1$ should be $n+1$.  With $n-1$ you need $n=9$ to make the expression greater than $30$

Comment: @RossMillikan Ohh that is true, thank you for pointing that out. Will edit it straight away

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake. I forgot to mention this : the sum of two numbers are equal or greater than 30

Comment: @Godlixe could you please edit the question in this case?